# Dynamic pages loading (without realoading whole page) in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I decided to learn AngularJS, but I got stuck on my first project :/

I want to make menu like in first example here: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/ So there are a few options: "home", "projects" etc. and if I click on one I get other part of site **without reloading whole page**.

What I want to accomplish:

- dynamic data loading, when I click on link, refreshes only one part of page not all. I want to [make page like this](http://pl.digipedia.org/b/list/news/1/) (click on any link - the menu bar sands still and isn't reloaded)
- all parts of site are in separate files (I don't want to keep all page data in one html file, I want to break it into pieces)
- adress of page (in browsers adress bar) is changing when I click on link

I know I could use AJAX or [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166691/load-instead-of-loading-whole-page-but-need-to-keep-menu-on-all-pages), but the problem is: I want to make Google-friendly site and - as in know - Google have some problems with AJAX based sites.

Can you tell me what way should I choose and if angularJS actually qualify to this job?

Comment: You are going to have to **really** narrow down this question because you could write pages and pages on these, and many of them are subjective. There are articles on [SEO with Angular](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) that you can read.

Comment: In terms of the routing the built in $route (google this) will provide you the capability to switch out one area with any number of views based on the URL.  If this isn't enough and you want nested views based on URL you can use ui-router (separate project but endorsed by core Angular team).  Regarding SEO as Josh mentions above this is it's own issue, there are solutions and I believe Google is probably working on solutions themselves to deal with AJAX based SPA type sites (but until that happens can prerender)